# Laravel HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, centos, centos7

In my server (CentOS 7), one of my Laravel 5 projects(the other projects work fine) is not working and returns HTTP ERROR 500.
I have all permissions for storage folder and everything is well, but this error is always diplayed
Version used for Laravel is 5.1 and web server lighttpd
I took a deep look the other similar questions but nothing helps.
Here my log file:

```
[2017-10-10 14:51:15] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
[2017-10-10 14:55:41] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
[2017-10-10 14:55:45] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
[2017-10-10 14:55:45] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
[2017-10-10 14:55:48] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
[2017-10-10 14:55:50] staging.INFO: Locale changed to en
```

any suggestion please?
Thanks alot

Comment: you can take look into access logs

Comment: Already done but doesn't help me ..

Comment: can u share you access logs too?

Comment: Enable debug...  If it's a web server error, it'd be your web server error log.  If it's an application error, it'd be logged in storage/logs (if debug is disabled)

Comment: Debug enabled but nothing returned

Comment: Then it's most likely a misconfigured environment and the error is in your error log for the web server.

Comment: I will check and I will tell you.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz check post updates.

Comment: please post Apache logs?

Comment: I said I am using lighttpd and not apache

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem ! 
I hope the solution will be helpful for someone in the future.
I did php artisan cache:clear and again chmod -R 777 storage and I tried and it works.

Comment: You should not chmod to **777**!  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others#answer-37266353) to solve your problem